# Grouped Boxplot with Latex

Tags: latex, boxplot

I am trying to create a grouped boxplot graph with Latex, in my case the table value for creating boxplot are very huge, so I can not loaded into Latex, instead I calculated Boxplot variable (median, whiskers and ...) parameters, in this case, how can I created a boxplot figure like this in Latex (this boxplot created by Minitab)

[image]

In most post about grouped boxplot with latex such as https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22619 , they assumed that table cloud be loaded and boxplot read all values from table which is not possible in my case